# Pitch Transformation in Unity 3D?

Tags: audio, transform, unity-game-engine, pitch

I am working on Unity3D and I am wondering if there is any possibility to transform an audio pitch like Talking Tom App?

If yes, is there any possibility to change the pitch while the audio is being played?

Answer (score 0):

AudioSource pitch modification, from [Unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AudioSource-pitch.html).